# Norm Property of a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let A be symmetric and positive definite. Show that $||a_{ij}|| < \sqrt{a_{ii}a_{jj}}$

Comment: What is the norm of a complex number? Do you mean its modulus?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's dealt with in linear algebra. Isn't it? @user1551

Comment: @Rama For just a single number, $|z|$ is used for the modulus of $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is positive-definite and symmetric, you have that $A=B^TB$ for a certain $B$. Then, using Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
|a_{ij}|=\left|\sum_k b_{ki}b_{kj}\right|\leq\left(\sum_k |b_{ki}|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_k |b_{kj}|^2\right)^{1/2}=\sqrt{a_{ii}a_{jj}}
$$

---

If you want to "start from scratch":

1. Considering the matrix as a complex matrix, show that it always has an eigenvalue.
2. Using that $A$ is symmetric, show that the orthogonal subspace of an eigenvector is invariant for $A$
3. Show inductively that $A$ admits a basis of eigenvectors.
4. Using said basis of eigenvectors, show that $A$ admits a positive-definite, symmetric square root $B$.
5. Write $A=B^2=B^TB$.

Answer (score 1):

of course. Every two by two principal subform must also be positive definite